# Pushing to cPanel: How to set up?

Tags: php, html, node.js, ftp, cpanel

As a self-taught developer I have always worked directly in cPanel to edit websites, which is obviously not the way to go. I am looking to figure out how I can start connecting local folders with cPanel so I can easily try changes locally before deploying them to the live website.

I have heard about FTP and checked out fileZilla but that seems to still be a manual process. I am looking for a way similar to using Git. Run changes locally, and then commit and push them to cPanel when all is good.

If anybody has any suggestions on the best way to go about doing this, that would be greatly appreciated. I'd like to work with node.JS if possible but just running php would also already be great.

Comment: FileZilla is actually a good choice.

Comment: Your question is [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using GIT itself. cPanel has now integrated GIT to its updated versions.

You can read more about this from below URL:
https://blog.cpanel.com/git-version-control-series-setting-up-git/

Comment: I'll check this out. Thanks!